# Create a alias property for a property inside an array

Tags: ember.js

Consider the following array,

```
auth: [{
    username: "",
    password: "",
  },
  {
    username: "",
    password: "",
  }
]
```

I am not able to add alias to a property inside the array like the one described below

```
defaultUsername: Ember.computed.alias('auth[0].username'),
username: Ember.computed.alias('auth[1].username')
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: what is 'deviceDetails' in your example?

Comment: Edited the code. I need to create alias for the auth[0].username and auth[1].username

Comment: give `'auth.firstObject.username'` a try

Comment: auth.firstObject.username works!! But how to alias for auth[2].username?

Comment: I couldn't make an alias work for the other case. But maybe you can live with a normal computed property: `username: Ember.computed('auth', function() { return this.get('auth').objectAt(1).username; }),`

Comment: I am actually binding it to template.. so i cannot use computed property.

Comment: you can also bind a computed property to template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168305/discussion-between-vishnu-prasath-and-jeff).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `firstObject` to return the first element
and `objectAt()` to get a specific element of an array.
I'm afraid the latter one won't work for an computed.alias()

```
  auth: [{
    username: "firstName",
    password: "",
  },
  {
    username: "maxmustermann",
    password: "",
  }
  ],

  defaultUsername: Ember.computed.alias('auth.firstObject.username'),
  username: Ember.computed('auth', function() { 
                   return this.get('auth').objectAt(1).username; 
            }),
```